# Post image with text on facebook from android

Tags: android, facebook

How can I post an image with text on facebook? I know how to post text, links, but I want to post an image as well.

Here is what I have tried:

```
 byte[] data = null;
 Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("R.drawable.plate1");
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
 data = baos.toByteArray();
 parameters.putByteArray("picture", data);

 int plate = getResources().getIdentifier("com.b2creativedesigns.eyetest:drawable/plate1", null, null);
 parameters.putString("picture", String.valueOf(plate));
```

Neither of them works. When I try to post, nothing happens. Nothing is posted. With the code below, it works.

Posting the image from a website is easy, but it will not work, when the website gets shutdown or the links modified.

```
  parameters.putString("picture", "https://lh3.ggpht.com/f79UCpnLisZxO2P2C43f55YLvFpNco_cTcC-t9Ck-Qmqe5jwKbfnUvCh5N6-Te-mOw=w124");
```

3rd example:

```
  byte[] data = null;
  Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("R.drawable.plate1");
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
  data = baos.toByteArray();
  parameters.putString("method", "photos.upload");
  parameters.putByteArray("picture", data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry, I shouldn't have gave advice on how to use the REST API since it's deprecated.  This is how you upload a photo to your own wall using the Graph API.

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putByteArray("photo", data);
params.putString("caption", "Test photo upload");
    mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST",
    new PhotoUploadListener(), null);
```

Please try this and see if it works.  This was taken straight out of our HackBook example in our documentation.  For the compression of the image, you can use our `Utility.scaleImage` method inside our SDK which will do all the compression and scaling to match Facebook's standards.

==================================================================================

ORIGINAL MESSAGE:

`photos.upload` is using the REST API and is deprecated so I would recommend using the Graph API to upload photos but here's the quick and dirty solution using the REST API.

Once you have the byte array in a variable like `data`, do the following:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
params.putByteArray("picture", data);
mFacebook.request(params);
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: updated my answer, please try my new suggestion and let me know if that works.

Comment: Is this going go create something like this? (http://www.johnhaydon.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/friends-can-comment.png)  See, this is a posted text, with a link and an image. I want this, not just post an image.

Comment: That is an open graph post and not simply posting an image.  You should read the documentation to do that here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Answer (score 3):

```
Session.openActiveSession(activity, true,
                            new Session.StatusCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void call(Session session,
                                        SessionState state,
                                        Exception exception) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    if (session.isOpened()) {
                                        fbSession = session;
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("caption", "Check this out, what do you think?");
    bundle.putString("name", name);
    bundle.putString("description", description);
    bundle.putString("picture", image);
    new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(HomeActivity.this, session, bundle)
            .build().show();
                                    }
                                }

                            });

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    default:
        if (Session.getActiveSession() != null)
            Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
                    resultCode, data);
        break;
    }
}
```

Add this code in your Android Manifest File, put your facebook id on place of FB_AppID.

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/><meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/FB_AppID"/>
```