# Post Image on Facebook wall using GraphApi not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post the image on Facebook using Graph api. I have converted the image into byte array and tried to post it , But i failed. Its shows the text posted on wall but the Image is not posting. I don't know what is wrong.

I already checked the below available solutions of SO ,but none of them worked for me.

1) [How to post image from drawable folder to facebook with graph api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295843/how-to-post-image-from-drawable-folder-to-facebook-with-graph-api)

2)[Unable to post an image from drawable to facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145375/unable-to-post-an-image-from-drawable-to-facebook)

3)[Post image with text on facebook from android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11916352/post-image-with-text-on-facebook-from-android)

4)[Android photo upload to facebook using graph api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788436/android-photo-upload-to-facebook-using-graph-api)

Here is the code which i am trying.

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
        byte[] bitMapData = stream.toByteArray();

        final Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", "Test FB Post.");
        params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
        params.putByteArray("picture", bitMapData);

       //Tried below code but not working.          
        /*try {
            String response = mFacebook.request("me/photos", params, "POST");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }*/
        WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(m_context,
                Session.getActiveSession(), params)).setOnCompleteListener(
                new OnCompleteListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                            FacebookException error) {
                        if (error == null) {
                            // When the story is posted, echo the success
                            // and the post Id.
                            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                            if (postId != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(m_context,
                                        "Posted story, id: " + postId,
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                finish();
                            } else {
                                // User clicked the Cancel button
                                Toast.makeText(m_context, "Publish cancelled",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                            // User clicked the "x" button
                            Toast.makeText(m_context, "Publish cancelled",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            // Generic, ex: network error
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Error posting story", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }

                }).build();
        feedDialog.show();
    }
```

Please guide me. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I already resolved my issue. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i resolved my problem to share image on Facebook using [Simple Facebook SDK for Android which wraps original Facebook SDK 3.5](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk)

This sdk provides simple way to share image on facebook wall using the resources which refer the [SimpleFacebook](https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook#specific-album) class.

You can publish (upload) photo to default album or to any other album you have. 
Photo can be created from:

- Bitmap
- File
- byte[]

> ```
> private SimpleFacebook mSimpleFacebook;
>  mSimpleFacebook = SimpleFacebook.getInstance(this);
>  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
>                     R.drawable.ic_launcher);
>    // create Photo instace and add some properties
> Photo photo = new Photo(bitmap);
> photo.addDescription("Screenshot from sample application");
> photo.addPlace("110619208966868");
> // publish
> mSimpleFacebook.publish(photo, new OnPublishListener()
> {
>     @Override
>     public void onFail(String reason)
>     {
>     mProgress.hide();
>     // insure that you are logged in before publishing
>     Log.w(TAG, "Failed to publish");
>     }
>     @Override
>     public void onException(Throwable throwable)
>     {
>            mProgress.hide();
>         Log.e(TAG, "Bad thing happened", throwable);
>     }
>     @Override
>     public void onThinking()
>     {
>      // show progress bar or something to the user while publishing
>       mProgress = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Thinking",
>     "Waiting for Facebook", true);
>     }
>     @Override
>     public void onComplete(String id)
>     {
>         mProgress.hide();
>         toast("Published successfully. The new image id = " + id);
>     }
> });
> ```